# C: Get substring before a certain char

Tags: c, string, char

For example, I have this string: `10.10.10.10/16`

and I want to remove the mask from that IP and get: `10.10.10.10`

How could this be done?

Comment: You can combine `std::string::substr()` and `std::string::find()`

Comment: if you're ok with destroying the original string, you can use `strchr('/') = '\0'`

Comment: you can also use `memchr` function, and then `strcpy`.

Comment: std::string or char*?

Comment: C or C++. The answer for one is not necessarily valid for the other language.

Comment: @pmg you are right. i need c. will edit.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just put a 0 at the place of the slash

```
#include <string.h> /* for strchr() */

char address[] = "10.10.10.10/10";
char *p = strchr(address, '/');
if (!p)
{
    /* deal with error: / not present" */
    ;
}
else
{
   *p = 0;
}
```

I don't know if this works in C++

Comment: wasted memory! all 3 bytes of it!

Comment: @75inchpianist What do you mean by that? Where is the memory "wasted" and how?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `*p =  '\0';`

Comment: @Shutupsquare: except in source form, `'\0'` and `0` are absolutely identical. The first is a literal character: it has type `int` and value `0`; the second is a literal integer: it has type `int` and value `0`. *Things may be different in C++. I don't know that language.*

Answer (score 36):

Here is how you would do it in C++ (the question was tagged as C++ when I answered):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string process(std::string const& s)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = s.find('/');
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        return s.substr(0, pos);
    }
    else
    {
        return s;
    }
}

int main(){

    std::string s = process("10.10.10.10/16");
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Comment: Im really sorry, c is what i need

Comment: thanks for the help i needed for a cpp projetct !

Answer (score 4):

```
char* pos = strstr(IP,"/"); //IP: the original string
char [16]newIP;
memcpy(newIP,IP,pos-IP);   //not guarenteed to be safe, check value of pos first
```

Answer (score 1):

Example in C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    std::string addrWithMask("10.0.1.11/10");
    std::size_t pos = addrWithMask.find("/");
    std::string addr = addrWithMask.substr(0,pos);
    std::cout << addr << std::endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example in [c](/questions/tagged/c)

```
char ipmask[] = "10.10.10.10/16";
char ip[sizeof(ipmask)];
char *slash;
strcpy(ip, ipmask);
slash = strchr(ip, '/');
if (slash != 0)
    *slash = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this is in C so I guess your "string" is "char*"?
If so you can have a small function which alternate a string and "cut" it at a specific char:

```
void cutAtChar(char* str, char c)
{
    //valid parameter
    if (!str) return;

    //find the char you want or the end of the string.
    while (*char != '\0' && *char != c) char++;

    //make that location the end of the string (if it wasn't already).
    *char = '\0';
}
```